# Unlimited variable in Javascript

Tags: javascript

I have a function that takes as parameter the number of messages to display. By default it sets this parameter to 20, I would like to pass it in unlimited so that it displays all the messages.

```
matrixClient.startClient(20);
```

Is there a variable like that ?

```
matrixClient.startClient(unlimited); ???
```

Comment: unlimited is undefined here. better to pass undefined itself and check if argguents is undefined do multiple display

Comment: The solution depends very much on how `matrixClient` is implemented. For example, if it exposes the size of the message you may have a `messageList.length` to pass to the method. But it's hard to tell without knowing what `matrixClient` is.

Comment: I implement my variable like this : `var matrixClient = sdk.createClient({
          baseUrl: "http://localhost:8008",
          accessToken: authContainer.access_token,
          userId: authContainer.user_id
        });`

Comment: Do you have access to `startClient`'s code? Can you change it?

Comment: @ibrahimmahrir No I can't change the code of startClient()

Comment: If `startClient()` doesn't support it, nor can you change it, there's no answer. Check out the docs.

Answer (score 5):

You could take [`Infinity`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Infinity).

> The global `Infinity` property is a numeric value representing infinity.
>
> The value `Infinity` (positive infinity) is greater than any other number.

```
matrixClient.startClient(Infinity);
```

Comment: @Floriane, what error do you get? do you have the code of the function?

Comment: This function is yours? Then adapt it to make it work. Arrays methods like `slice()` should accept. If not yours, then consult the docs

Comment: you could possibly have a look by getting the function in the console with `console.log(matrixClient.startClient);`.

Comment: No it's not my function. I use a library,

Comment: Looks like the library is [Matrix Client-Server SDK for JavaScript](https://github.com/matrix-org/matrix-js-sdk) should be in the original question.

Comment: so i suggest to test some great numbers, like `1e6` or greater, if necessary.

Answer (score 0):

If it is unlimited then you don't need to pass in the number, just spawn a new client or whatever as required